# fwrite() writes garbage at the end

Tags: c++

I'm trying to write a function that execute a sql file with postgres. Postgres rise me an exception but without specificate the error. So I tryed to rewrite what it read,  and I discovery that the file has some garbage at end

```
    stat("treebase.sql",&buf);
    dbschema= new (std::nothrow) char[buf.st_size+1];
    if(!dbschema)
    {
        wxMessageBox(_("Not Enough memory"));
        return;
    }
    if( !(fl=fopen("treebase.sql","r")))
    {
        wxMessageBox(_("Can not open treebase.sql"));
        delete []dbschema;        
        return;
    };
    fo=fopen("tbout.sql","w");
    fread(dbschema,sizeof(char),buf.st_size,fl);
    fclose(fl);
    dbschema[buf.st_size]='\0';
    fwrite(dbschema,sizeof(char),buf.st_size+1,fo);
    fflush(fo);
    fclose(fo);
```

and the result is

![screen shot][1]
The input file 150473 length, the output is 156010. I really can not undersand where  the 5000 bytes come from.
where is the bug?
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IXesz.png

Comment: Are you on a Windows machine? Are the `.sql` files text files or binary files?

Comment: You don't check the return value of fread.

Comment: @Ted Lyngmo yes is Windows and the files are text

Comment: @Özgür Murat Sağdıçoğlu: the only way to check the read is to write it down again, the compiler crash if i try to read 150.000 bytes with the watch variables

Comment: You should use "rb" and "rb" modes for fopen if the files are binary.

Comment: @SanPei No, there is a much easier way to check the read.  Namely `if( fread ( ... ) == ...)`, but you shouldn't be using `fread` at all.  If you are writing C++, use C++ idioms.

Comment: Postgres requires c stringe so work stright with c methods avoids memory shortage, and  I am not really Expert with file streams

Answer (score 0):

You probably can't read `buf.st_size` much of data, because of the mode of `fopen` is "r" which defaults to text modes. In text mode fread and fwrite may do some conversions on what you read or write to match the environment special rules about text files such as end of lines. Use "rb" and "wb" modes for `fopen` for reading and writing binary files as is respectively.

Also, I would rather use `fseek` and `ftell` to get the size of file instead of `stat`.

Comment: It's worked, It writes the exact amount of bytes, and postgres execute it without exception. I think I would never find the mistake. Thanks very much!

Comment: Özgür, binary mode is a good idea yet "In text mode only "text" characters are read and others ignored." is unclear.  What characters are _ignored_?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica That is a good question but I don't know exactly. That is why I put quotes around text. Maybe all it does is special character conversion in input/output operations to adapt to the system-specific text file format

Comment: I did not think, to use fseek and ftell, you are rigth

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of how you could read the content of the file into memory and then write down an exact copy to another file. I added error checking too to make it clear if anything goes wrong. There's also no need to use `stat` etc. Plain standard C++ will do.

```cpp
#include <cerrno>
#include <cstring>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <string>

std::string get_file_as_string(const std::string& filename) {
    std::ifstream fl(filename, std::ios::binary); // binary mode

    if(!fl) throw std::runtime_error(std::strerror(errno));

    // return the content of the whole file as a std::string
    return {std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(fl),
            std::istreambuf_iterator<char>{}};
}

bool write_string_to_file(const std::string& str, const std::string& filename) {
    std::ofstream fo(filename, std::ios::binary);
    if(!fo) return false;

    // return true or false depending on if it succeeded writing the file:
    return static_cast<bool>(fo << str);
}

int main() {
    auto dbschema = get_file_as_string("treebase.sql");

    // use dbschema.c_str() if you need a `const char*`:
    postgres_c_function(dbschema.c_str());

    // use dbschema.data() if you need a `char*`:
    postgres_c_function(dbschema.data());

    if(write_string_to_file(dbschema, "tbout.sql")) {
        std::cout << "success\n";
    } else {
        std::cout << "failure: " << std::strerror(errno) << '\n';
    }
}
```

Comment: Very nice, I should really learn the file functions of c++, thanks yiu very much

Comment: @SanPei You're welcome. Did it produce an exact copy like you hoped for?

Comment: I did not implement It, becauae libpq, the interfacce with postgres, requires a c string utf8 as input, so i create It stright with c methods, i do not know how to convert c++ string, to utf8

Comment: @SanPei You have the raw C string if you do `dbschema.c_str()` or `dbschema.data()` (if you need it to be mutable. It doesn't "convert" anything though. It will be exactly as it was in your file. If you need to convert it somehow, you can use the same conversion method you use on your C strings.

Comment: @SanPei I updated the answer to show what I mean.